# Python/Pytest: patched function inside pytest_sessionstart() is not returning the expected value

Tags: python, pytest

I'm trying to patch a function in Pytest's pytest_sessionstart(). I was expecting the patch function to return **{'SENTRY_DSN': "WRONG"}**, however. I'm getting back **<MagicMoc ... id='4342393248'>** object in the test run.

```
import pytest
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock

def pytest_sessionstart(session):
    """
    :type request: _pytest.python.SubRequest
    :return:

    """
    mock_my_func = patch('core.my_func')
    mock_my_func.return_value = {'SENTRY_DSN': "WRONG"}
    mock_my_func.__enter__()

    def unpatch():
        mock_my_func.__exit__()
```

Comment: can you also add the code where you call the function `my_func`.

Answer (score 1):

This has been correctly answered by @gold_cy, so this is just an addition: as already mentioned, you are setting `return_value` to the `patch` object, not to the mock itself. The easiest way to correct is is to use instead:

```py
from unittest.mock import patch

def pytest_sessionstart(session):
    """
    :type request: _pytest.python.SubRequest
    :return:

    """
    mock_my_func = patch('core.my_func', return_value = {'SENTRY_DSN': "WRONG"})
    mock_my_func.start()
```

This sets the return value to the mock without the need to create a separate `Mock` object.

Answer (score 0):

Issue here seems to be that you are not properly configuring the `Mock` object. Given the code you have shown I am going under the assumption that you are calling some function in the following way:

```
with foobar() as fb:
    # something happens with fb here
```

That call evaluates to to this essentially:

```
foobar().__enter__()
```

However, in the patching that you have shown, you have made a few critical mistakes.

1. You have not defined the return value of `__enter__`.
2. When you initialize a `Mock` object, it returns a brand new `Mock` object, therefore when you call `__enter__` at the end of your function, it is returning a brand new object, not the one you originally created.

If I understand correctly you probably want something like this:

```
import pytest
from unittest.mock import patch, Mock

def pytest_sessionstart(session):
    """
    :type request: _pytest.python.SubRequest
    :return:

    """
    mock_my_func = patch('core.my_func')
    mock_context = Mock()
    
    mock_context.return_value = {'SENTRY_DSN': "WRONG"}
    mock_my_func.return_value.__enter__.return_value = mock_context
    
    # this now returns `mock_context`
    mock_my_func().__enter__()
```

Now `mock_my_func().__enter__()` returns `mock_context` which we can see works as expected when we do the following:

```
with mock_my_func() as mf:
    print(mf())
>> {'SENTRY_DSN': 'WRONG'}
```